# Can I debug an app on IPAD with IOS7 using xcode 4.5?

Tags: xcode, ios7

I don't need to build and compile for IOS7, just debug on an IOS7 device.I don't want to upgrade my xcode to version 5.
I built an app using sdk 5.1
I run the app on an IPAD just upgraded to IOS7
I have to debug the app but xcode will not see the ipad, I get a message that I must upgrade my SDK. Does that mean I must upgrade xcode itself?
can I download just an sdk and continue using xcode 4.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeed in testing iOS 7 app within XCode 4 by first opening project from within XCode 5 and then running it from within XCode 4.

Since you are using XCode I suppose you have developer account.

So you do not need to migrate to XCode 5 as such. You can just download next version from Developer site as DMG file and you can run both XCode 4 and 5 as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug iOS 7 directly, but you can use the Organizer in XCode to view logs. You do this as follows:

1. Deploy to the device as normal (run, or create an ipa file and push
   to device) **Note:** If you run the application, XCode will go through
   it's standard processes and fail on execution. Just stop the
   application at this point.
2. In XCode 4.x, open the Organizer.
3. Navigate to Devices and open up the device that you have connected
   to your Mac.
4. Select Console for your device.
5. Clear the current logs by selecting the Clear button at the bottom.
6. On your device, run the application manually.
7. Now in the Console, you should see any logs that you've put in place in the code.

This isn't the most efficient way to debug, but it's definitely better than not having any way to do it at all. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by - "Create an ipa file and push to device" - how do you push an ipa file to a device via the Organizer